# Using Commands declared in "Parent" ViewModel (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

(Note: I chose to not use the Navigation Framework)

I have a WizardViewModel which is linked to WizardView.
The WizardViewModel declares and instantiates a command "Next".
It also contains a Property "ActiveSpell" of Type SpellViewModel.

The SpellViewModel contains several PageViewModels, each having a View counterpart.
The ActivePage Property (on SpellViewModel) tells the ui which view to take.

Now I have the following problem:
When I click a button to switch to the next page,
I need access to the "Next" command defined in the WizardViewModel,
but I only have access to a PageViewModel there.

I could just add a Parent property to each child ViewModel,
but I'm not sure if that is a good idea.
Or maybe there is another nicer/common way to do that.

Comment: it sounds like you might need to separate your Commands into their own class

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong, in MVVM with having child-ViewModels be aware of their parents. Indeed, you could use dependancy injection in the constructors for the child ViewModels, and *require* that the child be parent aware. Another way to handle it is to have the parent ViewModel subscribe to events raised by the children. However, as pointed out in the answer I upvoed, you will find life much easier, in large applications, to use an Event Aggregator, like Sailor described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Parent property. Your view model structure is good, just look at the picture, to understand how you should bind your view model onto the view:

[image]

Next command should be implemented something like that:

```
public void NextExecute()
{
    ActualSpell.MoveToNextPage();
}
```

**UPDATE:**
According to your comment, Arokh, I've updated the post.
I think, in this case you should implement ActivateCreatePersonSpell command in WizardViewModel.This command should:

- save actual spell state
- open CreatePerson spell
- once person is created set saved spell with result of creation person

The last what you need to do is to bind ActivateCreatePersonSpell command to button on the page. I propose to use **ViewModelLocator** for these purposes.Look at [this](http://blog.roboblob.com/tag/viewmodellocator/) post for example.

Comment: This is a good visualization, also. It might not be necessary for the child ViewModel to have access to the Next Command, if the control to go Next is part of the Parent View (rather than a child view).

Comment: This is actually the way I currently do it for the next/previous buttons.  But I want to build a Tree like Wizard instead of just a linear one.  For example a "Spell" might guide the user through the creation of a house and once the user has to specify the owner of the house, the user could click on a button on the active page which opens the CreatePerson Spell and once the Person is created the CreateHouse Spell resumes.  To that end I've created Enter/Leave commands. But since those commands are on the WizardViewModel I don't have access to them.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because I can image how I would go from there. But I went with a "Wizard" property because I think the problems introduced later on are less than the complexity introduced by using the ViewModelLocator, since my application isn't going to be very big. I'll certainly take a look at it again if that changes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Event Aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx), to adjust the interaction between ViewModels.

Comment: EventAggregator uses for decoupled view models or modules. Provided view model structure is coupled,so, no reason to use EventAggregator or another message aggregators.

Comment: As you can mention from comment to your answer, author wants to implement a wizard tree. So using the EventAggregator in such design seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had to implement a wizard once and I liked and mimicked the way Josh Smith and Karl Shifflett set up their WizardViewModel and wizard page view models in this example project (source code available with the article):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/InternationalizedWizard.aspx

They kept the Next command as part of their WizardViewModel, but created a WizardPageViewModelBase that all of the wizard pages derive from. That allowed the WizardViewModel to control which page is the current page, and it allowed the WizardViewModel to query the current page view model to see if the Next command can execute, thus enabling or disabling the Next button on the wizard. (That is, the wizard view model knew about the page view models, but the page view models didn't need to know anything about the "parent" wizard view model.)

As for adding links to parent view models, it's an approach that works, and I've done it before when I started working with MVVM, but after time I found the approach to result in some difficult to maintain code as every view model becomes interdependent.

Comment: Yes, I also based my implementation on that project. It helped me a lot, but since I want a tree like wizard instead of just a linear one, I need access to the Commands of the WizardViewModel from the PageView (At least that is currently the only way I can think of). See my comment on Vladimir Dorokhov answer, for more details.